# Ideas to avoid doing a trick on CyclicBarrier

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, cyclicbarrier

I was running some tests with parallel processing and made a program that given a matrix of integers re-calcutes each position's value based on the neighbours.

I needed a copy of the matrix so the values wouldn't be overriden and used a `CyclicBarrier` to merge the results once the partial problems were solved:

```
CyclicBarrier cyclic_barrier = new CyclicBarrier(n_tasks + 1, new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ParallelProcess.mergeResult();
    }
});
ParallelProcess p = new ParallelProcess(cyclic_barrier, n_rows, r_cols); // init
```

Each task is assigned a portion of the matrix: I'm splitting it in equals pieces by rows. But it might happen that the divisions are not exact so there would be a small piece corresponding to the lasts row that wouldn't be submitted to the thread pool.

Example: if I have `16` rows and `n_tasks = 4` no problem, all 4 will be submitted to the pool. But if I had `18` instead, the first 16 ones will be submitted, but not the last two ones.

So I'm forcing a submit if this case happens. Well, I'm not submitting actually, because I am using a fixed thread pool that I created like this `ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n_tasks)`. Since all the slots in the pool are occupied and the threads are blocked by the barrier (`mybarrier.await()` is called in the `run` method) I couldn't submit it to the pool, so I just used `Thread.start()`.

Let's go to the point. Since I need to take into consideration for the `CyclicBarrier` the possibility of that chunk remaining, the number of parties must be incremented by 1.

But if this case didn't happen, I would be one party short to trigger the barrier.

What's my solution?:

```
if (lower_limit != n_rows) { // the remaining chunk to be processed
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParallelProcess(lower_limit, n_rows));
    t.start();
    t.join();
}
else {
    cyclic_barrier.await();
}
```

I feel like I am cheating when using the `cyclic_barrier.await()` trick to raise the barrier by force.

Is there any other way I could approach this problem so I didn't have to do what I'm doing?

Comment: What about this: In the worker last to arrive to barrier (check via value returned by `barrier.await()`), you can check if there are items left to proceed. If yes, worker can submit new task to handle left-over items. Maybe, you'll still need to use some additional sync inside `mergeResult()` beyond `barrier.await()` -- just like you show with `t.join()`.

Comment: @VictorSorokin I don't understand how checking the return value of `await()` would help me to check if there is a left portion.

Comment: Aren't values of `rows` and `n_threads` known beforehand (before you start submitting tasks)?

Comment: Yes of course they are.

Comment: Then, why you can't add code to your worker `run()` which will check if `await()` returned 0 (last to arrive, hence barrier is released)  and if it's 0, then worker will check whether all items were processed?

Comment: Oh yeah I get what you're saying now. But exactly as you said, I would need some sort of synchronization in `mergeResult` because there would still be a portion of the solution to be resolved. It does not seem proper to me to call a merging method before all partial solutions are effectively calculated.

Comment: Yes, additional sync will be needed. Ok then, that's why I suggested in comments :)

Comment: I don't get the point. You can simply check beforehand, how many subtasks you'll need, don't you? (E.g. 18 / 4 is 4 with a remainder of 2, so 5 subtasks are required)

Answer (score 1):

Though this doesn't answer your question about CyclicBarriers, can I recommend using a [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html)? This does have the ability to include the number of parties, and it also allows you to run the `mergeResult` when a phase is tripped.

So, before you execute an async calculation, simply `register`.  Then inside that calculation have the thread arrive on the `phaser`.  When all threads have arrived, it will advance the phase and can invoke an overriden method `onAdvance`.

The submission:

```
ParallelProcess process = new ParallelProcess(lower_limit, n_rows));
phaser.register();
executor.submit(process);
```

The processor

```
public void run(){
   //do stuff
   phaser.arrive();
}
```

The phaser

```
Phaser phaser = new Phaser(){
    protected boolean onAdvance(int phase, int registeredParties) {
        ParallelProcess.mergeResult(); 
        return true;
    }
}
```